# keep left column fixed with css

Tags: css, html, css-position

I've been trying to get a layout with fixed header (works fine) and left column fixed too with scrollable content.

I have the following layout of div's:

```
    <header>
    <div class="header_content">
        <div class="search_box_area">
            <div class="input_box">
                <input name="search_input" type="text" class="main_input_search" maxlength="75" />
            </div>
            <div class="input_box_glass"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="advanced_search">advance search</div>
        <div class="icons_container">
            <div class="header_icon icon_1"></div>
            <div class="header_icon icon_2"></div>
            <div class="header_icon icon_3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="content">
    <div class="left_column">
        <div class="left_column_menu">
            <div class="left_menu profile_left_menu"></div>
            <div class="left_menu multi_left_menu"></div>
            <div class="left_menu calendar_left_menu"></div>
            <div class="left_menu app_left_menu"></div>
            <div class="left_menu contact_left_menu"></div>
            <div class="left_menu noticias_left_menu"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left_column_degraded"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="space_1"></div>
    <div class="main_user_content">
        -------- Here goes the scrollable content --------
    </div>
</div>
```

left_column has a set of icons vertically shown and always should be visible even if the the content scroll.

The CSS for each div is the next one:

```
header {
    width:100%;
    min-width:980px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height:43px !important;
    background-image:url(/images/header/header_background.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:999;
}
.header_content {
    width:980px;
    height:43px;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    top:-6px;
    width:980px;
    padding:43px 0 0 0;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.space_1 {
    width:18px;
    height:100%;
}
.main_user_content {
    min-width:520px;
    margin-left:70px;
    margin-right:380px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.left_column {
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0px;
    width:52px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
.left_column_menu {
    width:52px;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    height:100%;
}
.left_column_degraded {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-110px;
    width:110px;
    height:100%;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.left_menu {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    margin-bottom:13px;
}
```

The question is that '**left_column**' scrolls too and that's not the effect desired. What's missing in my code?

One thing is that all content (including the header) is centered even if it's resized horizontally.

Comment: Your left coloum is not fixed in css.

Comment: Well, ok, now it's been fixed the left column but the effect now is that when i resize the browser horizontally, it keeps fixed on the left instead of center as the rest of the content and header.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change your .left_menu rules position:

```
position:fixed;
```

based on what you are trying to do you would probably be better off creating a wrapper around everything with a 980px width and margin set to 0 auto, then instead of forcing the header and left sidebar to be fixed just set a height on the content and make it overflow hidden and scrollable

Comment: Well, ok, now it's been fixed the left column but the effect now is that when i resize the browser horizontally, it keeps fixed on the left instead of center as the rest of the content and header.

Comment: put it on jsfiddle.net and post a link

Comment: ok, but you didn't do anything I mentioned in my edit. There is no wrapper around the html, the header and left sidebar are still set to fixed, and the you didn't set a static height or overflow on the content area

Comment: wrapper included and left_column position set to fixed. The content class has the overflow:hidden

Comment: a wrapper needs to go around the header, left sidebar, and content... otherwise it's not really a wrapper. Also no fixed positioning, that's the point... if you have 3 elements on the page and 2 of them shouldn't move, it's easier to just make the 1 that does scrollable than trying to force the other 2 to stay still

Comment: sorry, i did not posted the new link with the updates..... http://jsfiddle.net/hvN7Q/2/

Comment: ok, remove `position:fixed` from header and left, set left to `float:right` and set main_user_content to `height:400px` and `overflow-y:scroll`... that should give you a good start